# How to get address of contract during migrations

Tags: truffle, contract-design, contract-deployment

There 2 contracts: Token and Crowdsale. To deploy crowdsale contract we have to know address of Token contract. How to get this address in migrations?

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");
var ERC20Token = artifacts.require("./ERC20Token.sol");
var ERC20Crowdsale = artifacts.require("./ERC20Crowdsale.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer, accounts) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
  deployer.deploy(ERC20Token, 1000, "Test Coin", "TCT");
  deployer.deploy(ERC20Crowdsale, THERE SHOULD BE TOKEN ADDRESS);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Truffle dependency documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations#deployer)

```
module.exports = function(deployer, accounts) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
  deployer.deploy(ERC20Token, 1000, "Test Coin", "TCT").then(() => {
    return deployer.deploy(ERC20Crowdsale, ERC20Token.address);
  });
};
```

Note - You should put your migrations into a different file than 1_initial_migration.js. It will cause problems when you redeploy. Leave `Migrations` in 1_initial_migration.js and put your deployments in 2_deploy_contracts.js (the filename can be anything as long as it starts with "2_"). From the [Truffle migration file documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations#migration-files):

> Note that the filename is prefixed with a number and is suffixed by a description. The numbered prefix is required in order to record whether the migration ran successfully. The suffix is purely for human readability and comprehension.